# Keep RGL window open after R QGIS script finishes

Tags: qgis, r, qgis-processing

I'm using the 'Processing R Provider' plugin to run some R code that uses the lidR package.

It's working fine except, when the script finishes, the RGL window that displays the 3D plots closes.

I was hoping to be able to review the RGL 3D plots to look for errors in the LIDAR data after the script finishes.

Has anyone found a way to keep the RGL windows open after the QGIS script finishes so they can review 3D plots?

LIDAR data is from here: https://webtransfer.vancouver.ca/opendata/2018LiDAR/4890E_54610N.zip

Code I'm running is below:

```
##LIDAR Processing=group
##showplots
##LAS_file=file

# Load required libraries
require(rgl)
require(lidR)
require(rlas)
require(rgdal)
require(tictoc)

# Load the las file into the system
data <- LAS_file

# Read the data as LiDaR
las <- readLAS(data)

# Plot LAS data for data check
plot(las)
```

I've tried preventing the script from finishing by using the sleep function in R and asking for user input before closing but QGIS seems to override this.

I'm using QGIS 3.18 | Manjaro Linux | and R 4.0.4

Comment: This could be done by sending the RGL graphics to a browser web page instead of the standard RGL window. This can be done with the `rgl` package functions but I can't see how to hook it into the LAS plotting function without rewriting chunks of `lidR` plotting code... Will investigate further if I get time...

Comment: Thanks @Spacedman. I'll take a look into this as well. I'm trying to use more non-Esri GIS software and R seems like the best choice for LIDAR but I'm pretty new to it. I don't think my coworkers will start to use it unless it is integrated with QGIS so my standalone scripts need to be converted - even then they will mostly probably stick to Esri

Comment: Found an easy way to capture rgl output - see answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default the plot goes to a new RGL device window, which will die when the R process finishes.

Instead you can direct RGL graphics to a web-based 3d viewer. To do that set a couple of `rgl` options so that you don't get the default viewer showing up, and then after doing the plot create a widget and print it:

```
options(rgl.printRglwidget = FALSE)
options(rgl.useNULL=TRUE)
plot(las)
widget = rglwidget()
print(widget)
```

that last `print` will collect the 3d graphics in the scene and create a web page viewer and open it in your browser. This will survive termination of the R process (and even the QGIS process).

Comment: @Spacdman thanks for this. It works!